# LIBGDX- Bind Skeletal animation to shader

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx, glsl

I'm trying to display my character in LibGDX with my own shader, but it dosen't seem to work.
I've tried to find more on Google and here on Stackoverflow, only finding this:
http://dagger.se/?p=71. Now I'm stuck..

My Shader that implements the Shader class of LibGDX:

```
@Override
    public void render(Renderable renderable) {
         program.setUniformMatrix("u_worldTrans", renderable.worldTransform);

         float[] bones = new float[renderable.bones.length];

         Matrix4 idtMatrix = new Matrix4().idt(); //Identity matrix

         for (int i = 0; i < bones.length; i++) {
            bones[i] = idtMatrix.val[i%16];
         }

         for (int i = 0; i < bones.length; i++) {
             final int idx = i/16;
             bones[i] = (renderable.bones == null || idx >= renderable.bones.length || renderable.bones[idx] == null) ?
                        idtMatrix.val[i%16] : renderable.bones[idx].val[i%16];
         }

         program.setUniformMatrix4fv("u_bones", bones, 0, renderable.bones.length); //Nor is the replacement of "u_bones" to u_bones (program.getUniformLocation("u_bones")) solving the issue.

         renderable.mesh.render(program,
                renderable.primitiveType,
                renderable.meshPartOffset,
                renderable.meshPartSize);
}
```

Vertex Shader:

```
attribute vec3 a_position;
attribute vec2 a_texCoord0;

attribute vec2 a_boneWeight0;
attribute vec2 a_boneWeight1;
attribute vec2 a_boneWeight2;

uniform mat4 u_worldTrans;
uniform mat4 u_projTrans;
uniform mat4 u_bones[3];

varying vec2 v_texCoord0;

void main() {

    v_texCoord0 = a_texCoord0;
    mat4 skinning = mat4(0.0);

    skinning += (a_boneWeight0.y) * u_bones[int(a_boneWeight0.x)];
    skinning += (a_boneWeight1.y) * u_bones[int(a_boneWeight1.x)];
    skinning += (a_boneWeight2.y) * u_bones[int(a_boneWeight2.x)];

    vec4 pos = u_worldTrans * skinning * vec4(a_position, 1.0);
    gl_Position = u_projTrans * pos;
}
```

The shader compiles without any errors is seems, but when I print out the following, I recieve "u_bones: -1" (All other uniforms receives a valid slot)

```
u_bones = program.getUniformLocation("u_bones");
Gdx.app.log("u_bones", "" + u_bones);
```

So somehow the program.getUniform() can't find the uniform "u_bones". Is it something to do with the shader, or the information I'm passing?

I've successfully compiled and animated my model with the default shader in LibGDX, but not with my own.

EDIT:
I found out that getUniformLocation("u_bones[0]"); returns a valid slot!, but the animation is still not working at all..

Comment: Anyone can see the problem? I'm still stuck and would very much appreciate some help!